# Can pyspark.sql.function be used in udf?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I define a function like

```
getDate = udf(lambda x : to_date(x))
```

When I use it in

```
df.select(getDate("time")).show()
```

I met

```
File ".../pyspark/sql/functions.py", in to_date
return Column(sc._jvm.functions.to_date(_to_java_column(col)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Does that mean that I can not use `pyspark.sql`.function in my own udf?

This is not a specific question, I wonder why this happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functions from `pyspark.sql.functions` are wrappers for JVM functions and are designed to operates on `pyspark.sql.Column`. You cannot use these:

- To transform local Python objects. They take `Column` and return `Column`.
- They cannot be used on the worker because there is no context in which they can be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at error seems problem with `sc` as `sc._jvm`:`'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'`

**Here sc is of NoneType.**

And there is no need to write `udf` for it, you can use directly:-

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.select(F.to_date(df.time)).show()
```