# Why is there a problem with the code? I am connected to the clusters

Tags: pyspark

I was trying to apply an UDF function to round those pct, maybe there are better ways, I am open to it because I am new to the pyspark.
When I removed the udf function to give up rounding the numbers, it worked so I am confident with the dataframe.

So guys, genius, please help me, love&peace

I tried spqrk.sql in databricks to get this dataframe and it looked good.

Here are the codes:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

round_func = udf(lambda x:round(x,2), IntegerType())

q2_res = q2_res.withColumn('pct_DISREGARD', round_func(col('pct')))

display(q2_res)
```

> ERROR:
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we can't use any of `pyspark.sql.functions` with udf. A detailed explanation is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691899/can-pyspark-sql-function-be-used-in-udf?rq=1) thread. You're trying to use `round` function, so it's not going to work, as it only works on columns. We can achieve the same functionality in a much easier way:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

q2_res = q2_res.withColumn('pct_DISREGARD', f.round('pct', 2).astype(IntegerType()))
```

It's usually advisable to avoid UDFs as much as possible because these are usually slower than native dataframe operations.